# Execution of custom command exiting R session

Tags: r

Is it possible to initiate a command, when exiting an R session, similar to the commands in the `.Rprofile` file, but just on leaving the session.
I know of course, that a .RData file can be stored automatically, but since I am often switching machines, which might have different storage settings it would be easier to execute a custom `save.image()` command per session.

Comment: Does defining the `.Last` function help you? https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/quit.html

Comment: That gave me the hint on reg.finalizer, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The help for `q` can give some hints. You can either create a function called `.Last` or register a finalizer on an environment to run on exit.

```
> reg.finalizer(.GlobalEnv,function(e){message("Bye Bye")},onexit=TRUE)
> q()
Save workspace image? [y/n/c]: n
Bye bye!
```

You can register the finalizer in your R startup (eg `.RProfile`) if you want it to be fairly permanent.

[edit: previously I registered the finalizer on a new environment, but that means keeping this object around and not removing it, because garbage collection would trigger the finalizer. As I've now written it the finalizer is hooked onto the Global Environment, which shouldn't get garbage collected during normal use).]

Comment: This does not work out-of-the-box here, since `e` is not defined. Would it be correct, by using `environment()` instead of `e`? Like
`reg.finalizer(environment(),function(x){save.image("custom.RData", compress = "xz")}, onexit=TRUE)`

Comment: Oops! I missed pasting `e = new.env()` from my first post, but I've now got a better method that doesn't need a new object, and won't trigger accidentally!

Comment: I've noticed that this does not always seem to work properly. It happend a couple of times that the RData file was not saved completely. Probably when the size is too big and it takes too long to save before the R session is killed.

Comment: I think I found the problem and it always occurs, when you are switching the Rproject from within rstudio. Perhaps then there's not enough time to save it properly.

Comment: If it always occurs then it sounds like RStudio isnt running the regitered finalizer. Perhaps it installs its own finalizers and overwrites yours? I may investigate....

Comment: I think it's not really an issue of rstudio. I think it was caused by the fact that I didn't load the .RData file automatically so it could happen that it saved an empty workspace, when I just opened the project without opening the data file. Sorry for the noise.